# Trying to delete file in ProgramData. Access is Denied, even as Admin

Tags: c#, windows, file, permissions

My code:

```
static public void DeleteFiles(string pathName)
{
    //expand path if it has variables. 
    pathName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathName);
    Console.WriteLine("Trying file: " + pathName);

    //if the file exists, delete it and say so. Otherwise, say so. 
    if (File.Exists(pathName))
    {
        try
        {
            File.SetAttributes(pathName, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete(pathName);
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            string lineToWrite = pathName + " deleted.\n";
            Console.WriteLine(lineToWrite);
            logList.Add(lineToWrite);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string lineToWrite = "Something went wrong... \n" + ex;
            Console.WriteLine(lineToWrite);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string lineToWrite = pathName + " not found.\n";
        Console.WriteLine(lineToWrite);
        logList.Add(lineToWrite);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it says it doesn't exist.

If I comment out the "IF" and the "ELSE" so it doesn't check for existence, then I get this error:

[image: Error]

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to path
>   'C:\ProgramData\pickles' is denied.

In my manifest file, I have the line:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

but it seems to make no difference. I've also tried "highestAvailable".

Does anyone know how I can alter my existing function in order to accomplish my goal?

Note: ProgramData\pickles does exist.

Comment: Is the file in use by another process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason seems to be that it is a directory. 
In exceptions of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx it says:

```
The caller does not have the required permission.
-or-
path is a directory.
-or-
path specified a read-only file.
```

Note: path is a directory.
What you might be looking for is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx
Directory.Delete(...

/Flipbed